# What are the pitfalls of merging exports via re-export in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

What I'm reading in TypeScript circles lately is *namespace BAD*.  However, I find utility and organizational benefit by encapsulating a collection of related declarations within a single namespace, somewhat like a library, and I want to avoid having to write copious import statements.

I understand a feature of import using **as** essentially allows for namespacing, e.g.

```
import * as NS from '../some/module'
```

However I see this as cumbersome and might prove messy if a need to refactor NS (in the example above)  arose.

So my strategy is demonstrated briefly below.  However I get a hackish feel from it, causing concern there may be unforeseen negative consequences which I am unaware.

Given the following folder structure

```
.
└── doc
    ├── doc.ts
    ├── impl.ts
    ├── exports.ts
    └── index.ts
```

**doc.ts**

```
export enum Type {
  A = "A",
  B = "B"
}
export interface IDoc {
  type: Type;
}
```

**impl.ts**

```
import { IDoc, Type } from "./doc";

export class Impl implements IDoc {
  constructor(public type: Type) {                      
  }
}
```

**exports.ts** exports everything

```
export * from "./impl";
export * from "./doc";
```

**index.ts** then re-exports 'exports' as **Doc**:

```
import * as Doc from "./exports";
export { Doc };
```

Then I have a single consistent import, for example

```
import { Doc } from "../core/doc";

export class SomeClass {
  doc: Doc.IDoc;
  constructor(type: Doc.Type) {
    this.doc = new Doc.Impl(type);
  }
}
```

What are the pitfalls of this strategy? Am I missing a best practice or pattern?

Comment: I'm doing something similar in a library of my own recently. Seems to work alright so far. But why not have `index.ts` just do what `exports.ts` is doing? Then you don't have one file exporting everything, and another shoving everything into a single object. This way you just have one file `index.ts` that maps your internal code to your external interface. [Example from my own library here](https://gist.github.com/Squeegy/674b85560638b7d05099231c61ef10f0)

Comment: @AlexWayne interesting, but I'm missing how I would merge all the disparate exports into a single coerced namespace given your example.  What am I missing?

Comment: `import * as X; export {X}` looks really bad to me. I have a feeling this makes a copy of all the imports, creates a new JavaScript object and exports it as default. If that is the case, you've broken barrelling and tree shaking in a single move.

Comment: @Reactgular I've confirmed 'exports.ts' does break tree-shaking.  I haven't verified whether a new object is created.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using a *namespace*. This technique is known as *barrelling*.

A **namespace** is usually built into the language and provides a way of uniquely identifying a set of "blueprints" like classes, interfaces, etc...

**Barrelling**, on the other hand, is what you are doing. Barrelling is wrapping up a bunch of exported members to have a single import. This is an ok technique, and may be recommended by others for what you are doing. Although, this technique could also lead you into a problem known as circular dependencies. **Circular dependencies** are a relation between two or more modules which either directly or indirectly depend on each other to function properly.

You just have to be careful when barrelling. You may also want to consider not doing it at all, and import specifically what you need in each file to avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Indeed the approach is flawed.  I favor a one class one file pattern, so I'll have to simply deal with many imports I suppose.